# Datetime Between in sql server up to the last milisecond .999

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, between

As the sql below it should return 2. But I run it the most new version of sql server it return 1.

```
declare @d datetime
select @d = '01-Aug-2017 00:00:00.000'
select case when ( @d between convert(datetime,'31-Jul-2017 23:59:59.999') and convert(datetime,'31-Jul-2017 23:59:59.999')) then 1 else 2 end

Return: 1
```

Did anyone ever meet this case. If met could explain about this.

Comment: Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql

Comment: This has explanation of how it will be rounded off : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql   From this link you can understand how datetime behaves

Comment: Read the links the other comments here point to and execute this sql: `select convert(datetime,'31-Jul-2017 23:59:59.999') as x`, this should tell you everything you need to know about this. Bottom line, `datetime` isn't that precise.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MS SQL datetime precision problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620627/ms-sql-datetime-precision-problem)

Comment: Thank all, base on Sujith's link. I think because of rounded and the datetime range only 00:00:00 through 23:59:59.997